# Google Photos Backup creates large Pictures/GPBackup folder

Tags: macos, backup, photos, google

I installed Google Photos Backups on OSX (Mavericks).  It created a /Users/rob/Pictures/GPBackup folder that is 10 gig in size, and it looks like it has copies of all my photos and movies.  I don't want it to use all this space, but didn't see any configuration settings for this.  What is the purpose of this folder?  If I just delete it, will Google Photos Backup continue to work?

Comment: I know the iPhoto and Photos Libraries do not actually contain the pictures and are really just a set of links to all the pictures on your mac, but when checking the size in Finder it checks all those links to tell you the size of all the pictures which is far greater than the amount of disk space the folder actually uses. (So basically don't trust Finder). If you delete it it will likely not release much storage space and Google Photos will just have to recreate the folder of links the next time it needs it. Can anyone confirm if it is the same with Google Photos Backup and iPhoto/Photos?

Comment: Did you get any further with this? Did you try deleting the folder?

Comment: No, I haven't gotten any further, and I have not tried deleting the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the "Google Photos Backup" icon in your menu bar (looks like a gray pinwheel), you should see the "Preferences" option.  Clicking this will open the preferences window.  There you should see a checkbox for "Also copy photos/videos from external media to" (See image below).  Uncheck this box and you shouldn't have the extra backups anymore.

[image: GP Backup Preferences]